# Multilevel linear modeling, multilevel SEM, and output for documentation using julia

Tags: statistics, julia

I was wondering if and how multilevel modeling such as hierarchical linear models (HLM), hierarchical generalized linear models (HGLM), structural equation modeling (SEM) and multilevel SEM can be conducted in [julia](https://julialang.org/)? Are there packages available for such analyses? (Equivalents in julia to `lme4`, `nlme`, and `lavaan` in R.)

I was also wondering about how to get julia's output into documents? Jupyter can obviously create markdown documents, but I was wondering about functionality for creating more complex documents similar to how knitr integrates R with LaTeX.

Comment: It might be helpful to spell out those acronyms, as I for one don't know what these things stand for

Comment: @NilsGudat Sorry, I didn't bother to spell out the acronyms because they are fairly common in statistics. I made the assumption that someone who would know the answer to my question would be familiar with the acronyms as well. Anyway, I've added the full spelling of the names to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with `nlme` and `lavaan` unfortunately, but the `lme4` equivalent in Julia is [`MixedModels.jl`](https://github.com/JuliaStats/MixedModels.jl), which is also developed by Doug Bates, one of the main `lme4` developers.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I checked the parent directory, and through that [this page](https://juliastats.org/). Unfortunately, I could not find any packages for SEM though. Could be that it has not been developed for julia yet..?

Comment: Btw, [`nlme`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/nlme/) is another package for **n**onlinear and **l**inear **m**ixed **e**ffect models.